# PHP Annotation Framework

Tags: php, annotations

I know that frameworks like Synfony2, Doctrine2, PHPUnit, etc... have support for annonations but I want to add in annotation support for my library but don't want to write the parser/caching myself.  Does anyone know if there is a library I can include/hook into my code and be able to start using annonations or at least provide a large set of functionality that does parsing/caching of the annonations for me?

Comment: [Reflection](http://br.php.net/manual/en/class.reflection.php)?

Comment: my biggest issue is how to handle cached of the annination

Comment: You need cache the result? You can use a session or a memory cache, like `memcached`, maybe store in a file, but for better performance, use memcached. Then you make a md5 of annotation, parse it like a DocComment, store and use. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflections are definitely the right path, yet you surely don't want to do all the parsing. [Nette Framework](http://nette.org/) has a class you might want to try: https://github.com/nette/nette/blob/master/Nette/Reflection/AnnotationsParser.php

Comment: Actually you can choose between New BDS and GNU GPL, that should not be likely to be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel. I suggest you to try the [doctrine2](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html) parser. It is simple to use and to install.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look: [test](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XjVasZ)

**Code**:

```
<?php

    /**
     * This is what you want.
     */
    function test() {
    }

    $ref = new ReflectionFunction('test');
    echo $ref->getDocComment();

?>
```

This works on PHP 5.2+.

Comment: This is the core *of* an annotation framework, but has nothing to do with annotations specifically.